# Swing -> JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, swing

Добрый день. Пытаюсь код (чат - сервер) написанный с использованием Swing сменить на JavaFX
Данная строка как я понимаю создает отдельный поток (не тот которым пользуется сервер)

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        log.append(msg + "\n");
        log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());
    }
});
```

чем в JavaFX можно заменить этот код?

Comment: `invokeLater()` в Swing (также, как и `runLater()` в JavaFx) не создает новый поток, а вызывает
указанный метод в единственном GUI-потоке, а если этот поток сейчас занят, то дает ему задание выполнить
когда он освободится.

Comment: А вот это действительно полезная информация, пойду погуглю что такое GUI. Большое спасибо Сергей

Comment: Правильно ли я понял. Поток GUI это графический поток, грубо говоря это те изминения которые происходят в ходе выполнения программы. У меня GUI поток стоит на выводе сообщений на textArea, а к примеру другой поток стоит на части кода который отвечает за подключения новых клиентов. То есть выполнять графические действия можно только в потоке GUI.
А все побочные можно выполнять в дочерних потоках ?

Comment: "GUI-поток" - это я так обобщающе назвал. В JavaFX такой поток получает название
"`JavaFX Application Thread`" (его можно увидеть в списке потоков в дебаггере).
Один поток для вывода сейчас, по-моему, используется в большинстве 
реализаций (Swing, JavaFx, Windows Forms, WPF, браузеры и др.). Это сделано для того, чтобы в функциях вывода не использовать межпоточную синхронизацию и этим их значительно ускорить.

Comment: Для "побочных" потоков в пакете `javafx.concurrent` имеется несколько полезных классов,
в которых предполагается, что управление созданными потоками будет прямо из "GUI-потока".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Platform.runLater()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) действует аналогично

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    log.append(msg + "\n");
    log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());
});
```